# Install PostgreSQL and PostGIS

Tags: postgis, postgresql

QGIS 3.10.2 in Ubuntu 18.04.

I'm having problems installing PostgreSQL and PostGIS following the instructions here: [Installing PostGIS under Ubuntu](https://docs.qgis.org/3.4/en/docs/training_manual/spatial_databases/spatial_functions.html#installing-under-ubuntu).

This doesn't work, `'postgresql-9.1-postgis'` isn't in the repository any more and has apparently been replaced with `'postgresql-10-postgis-2.4'`.

Would it be safe to attempt an install as follows?

```
$ sudo apt install postgis

$ sudo apt install postgresql-10-postgis-2.4
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try using a simpler way to install PostgreSQL and PostGIS:

```
> sudo apt update

> sudo apt install postgresql postgresql-contrib
```